# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

From this jQuery code:

```
$('#contentData').append(
  "<div class='media'><div class='media-body'><h4 class='media-heading'>" + 
  v.Name + "</h4><p>" + v.Description + "</p><a class='btn' href='" + 
  type + "'  onclick="(canLaunch('" + v.LibraryItemId + " '))">
  View &raquo;
  </a></div></div>")
```

What kinds of mistakes produce this Javascript Syntax error?

Comment: can you upload full code here ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You had a unescaped `"` in the onclick handler, escape it with `\"`

```
$('#contentData').append("<div class='media'><div class='media-body'><h4 class='media-heading'>" + v.Name + "</h4><p>" + v.Description + "</p><a class='btn' href='" + type + "'  onclick=\"(canLaunch('" + v.LibraryItemId + " '))\">View &raquo;</a></div></div>")
```

Answer (score 12):

### How to reproduce this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

This code produces the error:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run this and look at the error output in firebug, you get this error.  The empty function passed into 'ready' is not closed.  Fix it like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  });      //<-- notice the right parenthesis and semicolon
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the Javascript is interpreted correctly.

Comment: That was my mistake, after long pause of programming jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of hot to reproduce the error. It really helped me.

Answer (score 7):

For me, once there was a mistake in spelling of **function**

For e.g. instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

I wrote

```
$(document).ready(funciton(){

});
```

So keep that also in check

Comment: In my case, the error went away after I changed `( document )` to `('document')`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in below scenario yesterday. However I fixed it as shown below. But it would be great if someone can explain me as to why this error was coming specifically in my case.

pasted content of index.ejs file that gave the error in the browser when I run my node file "app.js". It has a route "/blogs" that redirects to "index.ejs" file.

```
<%= include partials/header %>
<h1>Index Page</h1>
<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
    <div>
        <h2><%= blog.title %></h2>
        <image src="<%= blog.image %>">
        <span><%= blog.created %></span>
        <p><%= blog.body %></p>
    </div>
<% }) %>
<%= include partials/footer %>
```

**The error that came on the browser** :

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in /home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/RESTfulBlogApp/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs

**How I fixed it** : I removed "=" in the include statements at the top and the bottom and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

**SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.**

**the issue also may occur if you pass string directly without a single or double quote.**

```
$('#contentData').append("<div class='media'><div class='media-body'><a class='btn' href='" + type + "'  onclick=\"(canLaunch(' + v.LibraryItemName +  '))\">View &raquo;</a></div></div>").
```

**so  always keep the habit to pass in a quote   like**

```
 onclick=\"(canLaunch(\'' + v.LibraryItemName  + '\'))"\
```

Answer (score -3):

**use:**

```
my_function({width:12});
```

**Instead of:**

```
my_function(width:12);
```