# show this JQuery error while executing in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.rc-anchor-normal .rc-anchor-pt').css('position':'absolute').css('top':'60px').css('right':'35px');
     $('.rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait').css('position':'absolute').css('right':'50px');
     $('.rc-anchor-logo-text').css('position':'absolute').css('right':'50px').css('top':'45px');


    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931344/syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list)

Comment: why multiple `.css()` why not one `.css({})`?

Comment: @cool, are you using Wordpress, by any chance?

Comment: yeah ,its a wordpress class.

Comment: @cool, I modified my answer to show how you should wrap your jquery code. Without this wrapper, `$` is not defined (alternatively you could use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your script). Basically you need to pass `jQuery` to your code as `$` in order for it to work.

Comment: @cool_benn was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 5):

The function `css()` expects function arguments as comma separated. You are using `css('top': '60px')`, notice that `:` there which is incorrect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('.rc-anchor-normal .rc-anchor-pt').css('position', 'absolute').css('top', '60px').css('right', '35px');
  $('.rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait').css('position', 'absolute').css('right', '50px');
  $('.rc-anchor-logo-text').css('position', 'absolute').css('right', '50px').css('top', '45px');    
});
```

> You should also keep habbit of looking at the browser console `F12` in chrome to check the errors you get while running the code.

You can also combine the chained `css()` into a single one using object representation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rc-anchor-normal .rc-anchor-pt').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'top': '60px',
    'right': '35px'
  });
  $('.rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'right': '50px'
  })
  $('.rc-anchor-logo-text').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'right': '50px',
    'top': '45px'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function can accept either 2 params, first is property name, and the second is the value, or one parameter that is of type JSON, which you tried to add but forgot curly braces `{ }`, so try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.rc-anchor-normal .rc-anchor-pt').css('position':'absolute').css({'top':'60px'}).css({'right':'35px'});
   $('.rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait').css({'position':'absolute'}).css({'right':'50px'});
   $('.rc-anchor-logo-text').css('position':'absolute').css({'right':'50px'}).css({'top':'45px'});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

.css function expects argument in a different way. You are passing the arguments in a wrong way. Correct and better way:

```
$('.rc-anchor-normal .rc-anchor-pt').css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'top': '60px',
  'right': '35px'
});
$('.rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait').css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'right': '50px'
});
$('.rc-anchor-logo-text').css({
  'position': 'absolute',
  'right': '50px',
  'top': '45px'
});
```

Refer: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: showing this error **VM11377:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:42**