# on change function throwing error due to missing bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery

Chrome console is telling me that the following is missing a bracket:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change', 'input[type='file']', function() { 
      
        });

    });

</script>
```

Any thoughts as to why? Thank you!

Comment: **'input[type="file"]'** single quote inside single quote causing error change with double quote or use slash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931344/syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to close single quotes properly. Replace this:

```
'input[type='file']'
```

with this:

```
'input[type="file"]'
```

---

This happens when we use quotes inside quotes and we don't escape the inner quote or use a different quote instead like:

**General Issue:**

```js
const text = 'input[type='file']'
console.log(text)
```

**Solution #1:**
<sup>(Using double quote instead of single qoute for the inner string)</sup>

```js
const text = 'input[type="file"]'
console.log(text)
```

**Solution #2:**
<sup>(Excape the quote using `\` before the qoute)</sup>

```js
const text = 'input[type=\'file\']'
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Should work just fine.

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function() {

      $(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function() { 
        //Do something here
     });

  });

</script
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is in the `'input[type='file']'`.

file should have double quotes, as the single quotes terminate the string, and chrome generates an unrelated error because that's what chrome does.

`'input[type="file"]'` should fix the problem